# Notification says "code edited on question", but there is no code in my question

Tags: discussion, global-inbox

Usually when someone edits my question, I'm receiving the notification in my inbox as **question edited**. But a few days before [Andrew T.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/241919/andrew-t) edited two of my posts, I received the notifications as **code edited on question**.

But I don't have any code block in those questions ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/277841/revisions) and [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/277839/revisions)), and this is the first time I'm seeing this **code edited on question** notification.

What was the reason behind that? Is that new notification introduced to Stack Exchange?

**Screenshot for reference:**

> [image]

**Usual notification on question edit:**

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was. In your posts, you had this line ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/277841/revisions), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/277839/revisions)):

> Stack Exchange Android App Version : `1.0.84`

The `1.0.84` is within an inline code block, which was removed. That was the code 'edited':

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Oh, my bad. I missed that inline code block. Thanks for notify.

Comment: @Arulkumar it's easier to spot in "side-by-side markdown" option, see here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ3CW.png (missed this answer and was about to post my own. :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard : Yeah, I was aware that option. But badly missed too. Anyway thanks for notify again. It may be due to Monday Fever.